# Extracting count of continuous non-zero values from vector

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

Suppose I have a vector

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,3,0,1)
```

I want to get how long the values in the vector are contiguously non-zero. Meaning for this case I want to get 7, 3, 1, 1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
with(rle(x != 0), lengths[values])

[1] 7 3 1 1
```

Comment: Can you help me extract at what position the maximum continuity stops? for instance here it happens at position 7.

Comment: wrap the above statement in `which.max()` and that will give the position of the max